# Combine two setcontentview in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, navigation-drawer, expandablelistview, expandablelistadapter, setcontentview

For the DoaHome.kt i want to put two setcontentview. The first one is setContentView(R.layout.cover_home_doa) for the navigation drawer. The other one is setContentView(binding.root) for the expandable list.

This the code of DoaHome.kt

```
package com.example.senangumrah

import android.content.Intent
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.View
import android.widget.ImageView
import android.widget.TextView
import android.widget.Toast
import com.example.senangumrah.databinding.ActivityDoaHomeBinding
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_persediaan_home.*
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.cover_home_amalan_selepas.*
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.cover_home_amalan_selepas.navigationView
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.cover_home_doa.*
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.cover_home_persediaan.*
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.layout_side_menu.*

class DoaHome : AppCompatActivity(), View.OnClickListener {

private lateinit var binding: ActivityDoaHomeBinding
private lateinit var listViewAdapter: ExpandableListViewAdapter
private lateinit var chapterList: List<String>
private lateinit var topicList: HashMap<String, List<String>>



override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    binding = ActivityDoaHomeBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
    setContentView(R.layout.cover_home_doa)
    setContentView(binding.root)
    onSetNavigationDrawerEvents()

    showList()

    listViewAdapter = ExpandableListViewAdapter( context = this, chapterList, topicList)
    binding.eListView.setAdapter(listViewAdapter)

    val btnback : ImageView = findViewById(R.id.buttonback)

    btnback.setOnClickListener {
        finish()
    }


}




private fun showList() {

    chapterList = ArrayList()
    topicList = HashMap()

    (chapterList as ArrayList<String>).add("Sebelum Berlepas")
    (chapterList as ArrayList<String>).add("Setelah Sampai")
    (chapterList as ArrayList<String>).add("Sebelum Masuk Mekah")
    (chapterList as ArrayList<String>).add("Ketika di Kaabah")
    (chapterList as ArrayList<String>).add("Ketika Tawaf")
    (chapterList as ArrayList<String>).add("Keluar dari Mekah")
    (chapterList as ArrayList<String>).add("Sebelum Masuk Madinah")
    (chapterList as ArrayList<String>).add("Ketika di Masjid Nabawi")
    (chapterList as ArrayList<String>).add("Ketika di Raudhah")
    (chapterList as ArrayList<String>).add("Keluar dari Madinah")

    val topic1 : MutableList<String> = ArrayList()
    topic1.add("Doa Naik Kenderaan")
    topic1.add("Doa Keselamatan Diri dan Harta")
    topic1.add("Doa Dipermudahkan Urusan")

    val topic2 : MutableList<String> = ArrayList()
    topic2.add("Topic 1")
    topic2.add("Topic 2")
    topic2.add("Topic 3")

    val topic3 : MutableList<String> = ArrayList()
    topic3.add("Topic 1")
    topic3.add("Topic 2")
    topic3.add("Topic 3")

    val topic4 : MutableList<String> = ArrayList()
    topic4.add("Topic 1")
    topic4.add("Topic 2")
    topic4.add("Topic 3")

    val topic5 : MutableList<String> = ArrayList()
    topic5.add("Topic 1")
    topic5.add("Topic 2")
    topic5.add("Topic 3")

    val topic6 : MutableList<String> = ArrayList()
    topic6.add("Topic 1")
    topic6.add("Topic 2")
    topic6.add("Topic 3")

    val topic7 : MutableList<String> = ArrayList()
    topic7.add("Topic 1")
    topic7.add("Topic 2")
    topic7.add("Topic 3")

    val topic8 : MutableList<String> = ArrayList()
    topic8.add("Topic 1")
    topic8.add("Topic 2")
    topic8.add("Topic 3")

    val topic9 : MutableList<String> = ArrayList()
    topic9.add("Topic 1")
    topic9.add("Topic 2")
    topic9.add("Topic 3")

    val topic10 : MutableList<String> = ArrayList()
    topic10.add("Topic 1")
    topic10.add("Topic 2")
    topic10.add("Topic 3")

    topicList[chapterList[0]] = topic1
    topicList[chapterList[1]] = topic2
    topicList[chapterList[2]] = topic3
    topicList[chapterList[3]] = topic4
    topicList[chapterList[4]] = topic5
    topicList[chapterList[5]] = topic6
    topicList[chapterList[6]] = topic7
    topicList[chapterList[7]] = topic8
    topicList[chapterList[8]] = topic9
    topicList[chapterList[9]] = topic10

}

private fun onSetNavigationDrawerEvents() {
    navigation_button.setOnClickListener(this)
    ll_First.setOnClickListener(this)
    ll_Second.setOnClickListener(this)
    ll_Third.setOnClickListener(this)
    ll_Fourth.setOnClickListener(this)
    ll_Fifth.setOnClickListener(this)
    ll_Sixth.setOnClickListener(this)
    close.setOnClickListener(this)

}

override fun onClick(v: View) {
    when (v.id) {
        R.id.navigation_button -> {
            doaDrawerLayout.openDrawer(navigationView, true)
        }
        R.id.ll_First -> {
            val button = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.menu_persediaan)
            button.setOnClickListener{
                val intent = Intent(this, PersediaanHome::class.java)
                startActivity(intent)
                doaDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(navigationView, true)
            }
        }
        R.id.ll_Second -> {
            val button = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.menu_kursus)
            button.setOnClickListener{
                val intent = Intent(this, KursusHome::class.java)
                startActivity(intent)
                doaDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(navigationView, true)
            }
        }
        R.id.ll_Third -> {
            val button = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.menu_amalansemasa)
            button.setOnClickListener{
                val intent = Intent(this, AmalanSemasaHome::class.java)
                startActivity(intent)
                doaDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(navigationView, true)
            }
        }
        R.id.ll_Fourth -> {
            val button = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.menu_doa)
            button.setOnClickListener{
                val intent = Intent(this, TempatZiarahHome::class.java)
                startActivity(intent)
                doaDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(navigationView, true)
            }
        }
        R.id.ll_Fifth -> {
            val button = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.menu_tempat)
            button.setOnClickListener{
                val intent = Intent(this,  TempatZiarahHome::class.java)
                startActivity(intent)
                doaDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(navigationView, true)
            }
        }
        R.id.ll_Sixth -> {
            val button = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.menu_amalanselepas)
            button.setOnClickListener{
                val intent = Intent(this, AmalanSelepasHome::class.java)
                startActivity(intent)
                doaDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(navigationView, true)
            }
        }
        R.id.close -> {
            showToast("Amalan Selepas Umrah Home")
            doaDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(navigationView, true)
        }
        else -> {
            showToast("Amalan Selepas Umrah Home")
            doaDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(navigationView, true)
        }
    }
}

private fun showToast(message: String) {
    Toast.makeText(this, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
}

override fun onBackPressed() {
    if ( doaDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(navigationView)) {
        doaDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(navigationView, true)
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed()
    }
}

override fun onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy()
}
}
```

when i put the two setcontentview...my interface is blank..the content not appear and the navigation drawer also does not function..then after that the application suddenly stop responding.

Answer (score 0):

`setContentView` sets the one-and-only root view of the Activity, so it only makes sense to call it once. If you want to use separate layout files for your drawer and your other content, you can create a top level layout file that defines the layout in it's entirety, and you can use [`<include/>` elements](https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/layout/improving-layouts/reusing-layouts) to include other layout files in this top-level layout.

Comment: which one i have to include the expandable or drawer